# Can opening a .py file in PyCharm be harmful/malicious?

Tags: python, pycharm

I've just started learning Python and have downloaded PyCharm and understand this is likely to be a very basic question but wanted to ask before I set off with a false sense of security.

I'm interested to know whether:

a) Simply opening but not running a `.py` file as a project in PyCharm IDE could be malicious.

b) Opening and running a `.py` file in the PyCharm IDE can be malicious

If not either, why not? Would the file need to be a .exe to do anything without PyCharm being involved?

Again, appreciate any help/insight you can provide.

Comment: You need an interpreter to run a .py file. Pycharm is an IDE. When you refer to Opening an .py file you effectively open it in a mode that allows you to view it's contents. if you want to run the file, you need to explicitly run that file. 
Opening a .py file can not be malicious but you need to make sure that it's not executable. Like you would need to make sure a text file is not actually a trojan.

Answer (score 0):

So just opening a file in PyCharm will not harm any computer in any way.
But running code can do that, so I would be careful were you get the code which you want to execute. And it would be best if you understood the basic of the code you are running. Therefore you would be able to spot strange lines in your code.

Comment: Thanks SebNik, I am aiming to learn as much as I can, as quickly as I can so hopefully will be able to do that soon.

Answer (score 0):

A Python source file (like any other programming language) is just a plain text file, so until the instructions that are written in the file are evaluated (by the [python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html) in this case) the file itself cannot be in any way harmful.
Only once you run `python myfile.py` in a shell or by using an IDE like PyCharm the code is actually executed... at that point what happens depends on what is written in the file (which you can check before executing it).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Yes, I had opened the file and it seemed to open in a sort of restricted format in PyCharm and when I then selected 'Open File in Project' it deleted the file I was working on and opened the new file and CPU % went up significantly even though I didn't actually run the code. I'm starting to think that might have been normal and I just haven't learnt the program properly yet.